# How to use more than 1 schema.org schema on a web page

Tags: html, html5, schema.org, json-ld

How do you add more than one schema to a web page?

I am using the `Organization` and `WebSite` schemas on my home page. I am writing the markup in JSON-LD format.

The `Organization` schema for the knowledge graph:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
     {
          "@@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@@type": "Organization",
          "name": "My Website Name",
          "url": "http://www.example.com",
          "sameAs": [
               "http://www.facebook.com/example-com",
               "http://www.instagram.com/example-com"
          ]
     }
</script>
```

and the `WebSite` schema to include my site name in search results (if Google ever decides to implement this):

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
     {
          "@context" : "http://schema.org",
          "@@type" : "WebSite",
          "name" : "My Website Name",
          "url" : "http://www.example.com"
     }
</script>
```

As you can see they both have the same `name` and `url` properties.

Do I need to specify the 2 separate like I did or can just concatenate the 2? Any preference of which has to go first on the page?

**UPDATE 23 February 2016:**

I ended with the following using unor's help:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
     {
          "@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@graph": [{
               "@type": "WebSite",
               "name": "My Website Name",
               "url": "http://www.example.com"
          }, {
               "@type": "WebPage",
               "name": "My Website Name",
               "url": "http://www.example.com"
          }, {
               "@type": "Organization",
               "name": "My Website Name",
               "url": "http://www.example.com",
               "sameAs": [
                    "http://www.facebook.com/example-com",
                    "http://www.instagram.com/example-com"
               ]
          }]
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In JSON-LD ([instead of Microdata/RDFa](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/85878/17633)) you have to repeat the property and its value for each node.

Instead of using [a separate `script` element for each node](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30730343/1591669), you could also use [a single `script` element that contains all your nodes as value of `@graph`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33457312/1591669). That way you only have to define the `@context` (and possibly custom properties) one time.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@graph": 
  [
    {
       "@type": "WebSite"
    },
    {
       "@type": "Organization"
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

The order of the `script` elements (or the nodes in `@graph`) shouldn’t matter

Comment: I edited my original post to include an answer based on your recommendation. I have shared the code that I used for my home page. Could you please comment on the way and nodes that I used. Does it look correct? Any redundant data?

Comment: Where do you get all your knowledge from regarding structured data? I have searched high and low using Google but never have I found any answers or blog posts with answers like yours.

Comment: any advantage to using `@graph` vs just passing an array of `@type` objects?

Comment: @RonRoyston: I wrote about it [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48295719/1591669) (tl;dr: the disadvantage with the `@graph`-less array is that you have to repeat the `@context` per item)

Answer (score 4):

Not looking to be a necromancer, but there was a recent article from someone at Yoast that details problems that arise with using the @Graph type when trying to get Google search to "report" the subsequent types, especially with Organization data: [link](https://www.jonoalderson.com/conjecture/google-have-to-improve-their-structured-data-reporting/)

I would recommend breaking out each type into its own "node" for now instead of using @graph as an array, especially since I can't find a single mention of using @graph with JSON-LD in any of Google's Developer documentation.

Comment: Upvoted this, because I can't either. It's almost as if people just started using @graph and I have no idea why. I can't find official documentation on it.

Comment: It's easier to add itemTypes programmatically when one uses @Graph, so a lot of plugins (e.g. Yoast) ran with it. Doesn't mean it's a good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

**If you already add website URL in organization, then you don't need to add website schema in your website.**

If you're using organization schema, then I suggest to use logo properties as well.

```
"logo": "http://www.example.com/logo.png"
```

Another thing, I want to say, Google does not support all the schema and it's properties, so use those schema, which is [currently supported by Google](https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2013/05/using-schemaorg-markup-for-organization.html).

Answer (score -2):

You can definitely concatenate them. I have seen it done on a lot of websites. As an example check how it is done on https://yoast.com . And the structured data validation tool from Google seems to say the code is ok.