# Multiple Schema.org types on a page?

Tags: schema.org

What is the best method for using multiple Schema.org types for a website? I want to use different structured data types because seem like they are relevant to both `Organization` and `LocalBusiness` types. However, I am not sure if that is correct and how Google will interpret the data.

For example, if a website is a "preschool", it is under an `Organization` type. But since they also provide "child care", it is also under `LocalBusiness`. On top of that, I am not sure if it's relevant to include the `WebPage` or `WebSite` type schema.

Is this overkill to include multiple types? I like the fact that you can include opening hours under `LocalBusiness`. If it's good to include multiple types, do you need to include the URL info twice like the logo, url, social properties? Please see snippet below.

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@graph":
[
{
  "@type": "Organization",
  "name": "Preschool Name",
  "url": "https://www.website.com",
  "logo": "https://www.website.com/logo.jpg",
  "sameAs": "https://www.facebook.com/preschool-name"
},
{
  "@type": "ChildCare",
  "name": "Preschool Name",
  "image": "https:/www.website.com/logo.jpg",
  "@id": "https://www.website.com/#website",
  "url": "https://www.website.com",
  "telephone": "999-999-9999",
  "priceRange": "$$$",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "123 Road",
    "addressLocality": "Los Angeles",
    "addressRegion": "CA",
    "postalCode": "12345",
    "addressCountry": "US"
  },
  "openingHoursSpecification": {
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": [
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday",
      "Saturday",
      "Sunday"
    ],
    "opens": "00:00",
    "closes": "23:59"
  },
  "sameAs": [
    "https://www.facebook.com/preschool-name",
    "https://www.website.com"
  ]
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[LocalBusiness](https://schema.org/LocalBusiness) is a sub type of [Organization](https://schema.org/Organization). This means you can merge the details you added for organization into your LocalBusiness and they will still be understood as being part of the Organization. And then not need to duplicate things in a separate entity.

e.g. move all the properties from Organization to the LocalBusiness entity, and then remove the empty Organization.

Answer (score 0):

Yoast (plugin for wordpress) does a great job by using @graph and connecting all those lose entities together, by carefully planning everything, and using @id to, as they say "glue" things together.
Take a look at [this article](https://yoast.com/schema-org-is-hard-were-making-it-easy/), you will get much better understanding of what I am talking about.

Comment: Thank you. yes, we are using Yoast and it does a basic setup of WebPage and "isPartOf" properties to glue things together like you mentioned. I just am not sure if it's better to use your own JSON-LD because we also want to use the "LocalBusiness" type. Perhaps we need to make a change to the plugin files?

Comment: On @graph and Google: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/90300/how-to-use-more-than-1-schema-org-schema-on-a-web-page/127026#127026